# Strange race condition: FileNotFoundError with mkdtemp

Tags: python, race-condition, temporary-directory

I am getting a rather bizarre race condition in Mac OS X with Python (I've only tested Python 3.3). I am making several temporary directories, writing things to them, and then clearing them.  Something along the lines of

```
while running:
    (do something)
    tempdir = mkdtemp('name')
    try:
        (write some stuff to tempdir)
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(tempdir)
```

However, in some of the later loops of the `(write some stuff to tempdir)`, I get errors like

```
    with open(os.path.join("/var/folders/yc/8wpl9rlx47qgzxqpcf003k280000gn/T/tmp0fh2ztname", "file"), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fn:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/yc/8wpl9rlx47qgzxqpcf003k280000gn/T/tmpups5dpname/file'
```

(I've inlined the temp dir path for clarity)

Notice how the path being opened is not the same as the path that it can't find. In each case, the path in the error message is the temporary directory from the previous iteration of the loop.

The error is reproducible most of the time in the same place (after about the fourth iteration), but not every time.

EDIT: I just realized this is probably relevant. The `(write some stuff to tempdir)` stuff actually happens in a subprocess. This is how I am sure about the tempdir path, I have to pass it on to the subprocess (I actually lied about the "clarity" bit, I am actually writing out a Python file with that exact `with open` line). This is how I know for sure that the tempdir path is indeed different from the one being used.

Comment: Are you sure about the path? How about doing the os.path.join above the with, catch the error and print out what the path was? Coding errors are more likely than fundamental language errors!

Comment: I justed added some more information. Actually, now that I think about it, maybe I *can't* trust the traceback output. Maybe the race condition comes from reading the cached pyc file (I am writing to the same file in each instance).

Comment: You can run Python using `python -c [code]`. In subprocess it is quite easy to just pass an arbitrary block of code (including newlines and indentation). This would avoid having to create Python files on-disk and risking some filesystem or Python bytecode caching race.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out it has nothing to do with mkdtemp (a sigh of relief that Mac OS X and Python are doing the right things there).

The problem is that I was writing out the code to a file, including the `with open(os.path.join("/var/folders/yc/8wpl9rlx47qgzxqpcf003k280000gn/T/tmp0fh2ztname", "file"), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fn:` bit, and running it in a subprocess. The issue was that I was using the *same* file each time, and the .pyc files were not being invalidated correctly.

The error message was confusing because when Python generates a traceback, it reads the `.py` file (where the actual code is), but what is actually run is the `.pyc` file.

If I understand http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html correctly, the timestamps in `.pyc` files ony have one second granularity (this explains why this was reproducible in the same place each time: the same fourth item in the loop ran in under a second).

The solution was to explicitly delete the .pyc files when writing out the file (in other circumstances you could also write out to a temp file itself, but in my case I needed the file to be importable under the same name).

Something along the lines of

```
if sys.version_info >= (3,):
    os.unlink(os.path.join(path_to_file, '__pycache__', 'file.cpython-%s%s.pyc' % sys.version_info[:2]))
    os.unlink(os.path.join(path_to_file, '__pycache__', 'file.cpython-%s%s.pyo' % sys.version_info[:2]))
else:
    os.unlink(os.path.join(path_to_file, 'file.pyc'))
    os.unlink(os.path.join(path_to_file, 'file.pyo'))
```

Comment: +1 Interesting case, maybe you could accept you own answer, so the question will appear as "solved" in SO searches.

Comment: Yes, I had planned to. SO only lets you accept your own answer after 48 hours.